# Exception messages and already headers sent error while developing

Tags: php, exception

In my development machine I have error_reporting set to `E_ALL | E_STRICT` to see all the error messages that happen in my code. 
But when I deal with caught Exceptions like:

```
try {
   throw new MyException('Exception message.');
} catch (MyException $e) {
    // code that handles the exception but without print anything
}
```

PHP always shows the error message:

```
MyException: Exception message in file://path/to/failed/file.php
```

and after that PHP can't send new headers.

Do you know some way to avoid autogenerated PHP errors to be shown by raised, but caught, Exceptions with `display_errors=On` and `error_reporting=E_ALL |E_STRICT`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a custom error handler and have that log errors to a file or something like this. Information on this can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Answer (score 0):

If you print the message, headers will be sent, period. If you do not need to print it, don't. You could log it, instead.

Comment: I'm not printing the message, is the PHP error handler that prints the message. I want to avoid this.

Comment: From your question: `echo $e->getMessages();`. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: The code is: try {
   throw new MyException('Exception message.');
} catch (MyException $e) {
   //php code that handles that error but doesn't print anything
}

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that was my fault.

If you have xdebug installed and if your xdebug configuration has
xdebug.show_exception_trace = 1

allways an exception is raised xdebug will dump the stack trace.